# High CPU Utilization in WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 - Thread spinning (stuck thread)

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2

We are running WSO2 API Manager version 3.1.0 and we are frequently coming across high CPU utilization. After taking a thread dump, we found that we are having a thread that keep running for long time which we suspect could be the potential root cause of the issue. Here is the thread stack trace:

```
"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-3" #3286 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb0e4e78000 nid=0xd05 runnable [0x00007fb072b56000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flush(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractContentEncoder.flushToChannel(AbstractContentEncoder.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkEncoder.write(ChunkEncoder.java:129)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.consume(Pipe.java:159)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceResponse.write(SourceResponse.java:279)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler.outputReady(SourceHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:312)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:127)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onOutputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onOutputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Did anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: This seems like a general I/O processing thread, which if you've got a lot of connections, could easily be reused by a lot of connections. Of course, if you have a lot of connections then you'll see a high CPU but this thread just seems to be part of the I/O processing of your WSO2 API manager.

Comment: Could you state the OS and JRE version, as well how many connections / clients are you having? All parameters for the http connections, JVM parameters, .. or are oyu using only defaults?

Comment: We are using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and java version "1.8.0_171". Most of the configuration is left as defaults. Does this mean that we need to increase CPU allocated for the server?

Answer (score 0):

malfaris,

The thread you have mentioned in the description is a reactor thread that runs all the time with the product. Hence, it will not imply high usage was occurring from that thread.

Capture thread usage and thread dump when you observing the CPU spikes.

Thread usage

`ps -C java -L -o pcpu,cpu,nice,state,cputime,pid,tid > thread-usage.txt`

Thread dump

`jstack <pid> > thread-dump.txt`

Thread usages will give you the information about higher CPU consuming threads and you can analyze the stack trace of the threads by mapping the thread id converted to Hexa value with the thread dump.

https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps

Comment: The thread stack trace above is identified by following the steps you are mentioning. Here is the thread usage for the highest CPU: %CPU CPU  NI S     TIME   PID   TID
74.0   -   0 R 2-07:16:03  67  3333 . Does this mean that there is a shortage in CPU allocated for the WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: There could be 3 scenarios for high CPU. 1. allocated CPU cores are not sufficient 2. System load is high (having too many connections and high TPS) 3. Reactor thread spinning (if this is the case, the CPU will never go down even if the TPS is getting lower). Please try to increase the CPU resources (cores) and check again.

Comment: The above 3 scenarios are only applicable to reactor threads. there could be other possible reasons for various threads.